# Extracting directory/subdirectory name from absolute path in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to walk down full path to a `file` and list the last two `parent directories`

eg:

```
\\publicshare\products\apps\123.456\OSfile
```

I want to extract `123.456` and `OSfile` in my batch script.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET MYPATH=\publicshare\products\apps\123.456\OSfile

for %%i in ("%MYPATH%") do SET FIRST=%%~nxi&SET MYPATH=%%~dpi
SET MYPATH=%MYPATH:~0,-1%
for %%i in ("%MYPATH%") do SET SECOND=%%~nxi

echo %FIRST%    -- echoes OSFile
echo %SECOND%   -- echoes 123.456
```

The first FOR statement extracts the filename+extension (%%~nxi), then sets MYPATH to the remainder of the path (drive letter + path).

"SET MYPATH=%MYPATH:~0,-1%" removes the trailing backslash.

The second FOR statement extracts the last element from MYPATH, which is now the directory.

Comment: There is no need to modify value of MYPATH. Simply use `for %%i in ("%MYPATH%\..") do set "SECOND=%%~nxi"`

Comment: @dbenham, that's true enough, there's more than one way to skin a cat.